# how to reload a pythonic service on centos 7?

Tags: linux, service, centos7

I have a python app that I made it as a service on centos 7.
I created a file in /usr/lib/systemd/system with my project name. And wrote these on it:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/src/python-project/sampleService-services/serverprotocol.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable sampleService.service
$ sudo reboot
```

I can start, restart and stop this service with commands:

```
$ systemctl start sampleService.service
$ systemctl restart sampleService
$ systemctl stop sampleService
```

But when i try to reload it with these commands:

```
$ systemctl reload sampleService
```

or

```
$ service sampleService reload
```

I get this error:

> Failed to reload sampleService.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit basiscore.service.
>   See system logs and 'systemctl status sampleService.service' for details.

Is there any command for reload this pythonic service ?!

how can I reload my service without restarting it ?!

Answer (score 1):

Under the `ExecStart=` line, try to add

```
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
```

Answer (score 1):

For `systemctl reload ...` to work, you need to provide an `ExecReload=` line in your unit (service) file.  A common example is:

```
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

That requires your program to catch and act on a SIGHUP signal.  If your application has a different mechanism to trigger a reload of its configuration while running, then provide some other suitable command which generates that trigger.